# Ios passcode effect in Android

Tags: java, android, ios

Is there a way to create in Android, an on button pressed effect like Ios passcode ones?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/86jW0.gif

Comment: It seems to me this is just simple onClick fade in animation with some kind of drawable, and onRelease the same animation backwards. Anything more to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
    btn.startAnimation(animation);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            view.clearAnimation();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That was almost what i wanted to. I want this to happen in onClick(i made it) but i want the background to be like the ios one. Is there a way? Thanks!!